# How to accumulate dividends over time?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a project that I simply can't wrap my head around how to construct, and I hope you can help me out.

### The scenario

The user gets to add stocks to a portfolio so that he/she over time can visualize the dividend growth. The stocks in each portfolio are managed as such:

`Date         Stock   Change`
`2018-01-14   2       +10`
`2018-01-18   2       -2`
`2018-01-20   5       +1`

In a separate table, the stocks' dividends are collected. This table simply contains the stock ID, the ex-dividend date (when the "right" to the dividend is given to you, if you own the stock), the payout date and the payment amount.

## The task

Now, what I can't figure out is how to iterate through the time of these aspects to correctly accumulate the dividend growth over time;

1. Let's say the ex-dividend date of share #2 is at 2018-01-19.
2. At that moment in time this portfolio receives the right to 8 shares' dividends.
3. At the payout date, this portfolio's dividend accumulates with the dividend value of the shares it has the right to.

Could someone please point me in the right direction? How should I construct the array containing these values?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a simple query with a filtering condition do? For example:

```
select sum(change) as total
from my_table
where stock = 2 -- #2
  and date <= '2018-01-19' -- filter the rows by date
```

Result:

```
total
-----  
8
```

Comment: Well, perhaps; for one dividend with a known date. There are hundreds of stocks which each have many dividends, spanning over several years.

Comment: Then, I fail to understand your question.